# Solace SEMP - How to find hardware/firmware versions

Tags: solace

Please, using Solace SEMP, how can I find which is the current appliance hardware and firmware version?

I tried https://${Solace_IP}/SEMP/v2/config/ and https://${Solace_IP}/SEMP/v2/config/about with no lucky

https://${Solace_IP}/SEMP/v2/config/about/api shows SEMP version, but not Firmware/Hardware versions!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SEMP v2 to retrieve the SolOS version if you have version 10.1.0+.

`curl -X GET -u mgmt_username:password 192.168.XXX.XX:PORT/SEMP/v2/monitor` and you'll see the version under `data.version`

SEMP v2 doesn't yet show the hardware details, but you can find them using SEMP v1. More info in the [docs](https://docs.solace.com/Admin/SEMP/Using-Legacy-SEMP.htm), but something like this should do it for you:

```
  <rpc>
      <show>
         <hardware><details/></hardware>
      </show>
  </rpc>
```